# Dropdown menu doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get my dropdown menu to work, but for some reason, it doesn't appear in the browser.

I already checked the other questions and couldn't find a reason for my problem. I already removed *overflow:hidden* from my parent list, even though the gradient I had in the navbar disappeared because of that and I don't know how to fix that either.

I used [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) for help (although they didn't use a list, which is a requirement) and a template from one of my friends that I even copypasted into my css and it **still didn't work**.

Okay, so for your reference, here you have my CSS and HTML:

```css
body {font-family: "Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS";
  width: 780px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555555}

#site {background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;}

/** My Friend's CSS that didn't work either

.main li {list-style-type: none; 
  float: left; 
  width: 150px; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
  text-align: center;}

.main li:hover {color: white;}

.main2 li {display: none; 
  background-color: lightgrey; 
  color: black;}
.main2 li:hover {background-color: grey; 
    color: white;}

.main li:hover .main2 li {display: block;}**/




.main {list-style-type: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
  width: 100%}

.main li {display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative}

.main li a {display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 12px 5px 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;}

.main a {text-decoration: none;
  color: black;}

.main2 li {position: absolute;
   display: none;
   width: 100%
   }
.main li a:hover .main2 li {display: block;}

.main2 li a {color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="site">
 <nav>
  <ul class="main">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Über mich</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <ul class="main2">
     <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
    </ul>
   <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
    <ul class="main2">
     <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Insta</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

also, here's a screenshot of how the website looks like at the moment (I only included the important parts of the HTML because I actually haven't formatted the rest of the site in CSS

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr85P.png)

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, I commented the changed code.
The problem is that your `<ul class="main2">` is in the same level as the other `li` which is not valid.

I olso changed this line of css

```
.main li a:hover .main2 li {display: block;}
```

to

```
.main li:hover .main2 li  {display: block;}
```

### Edit

For the gradient problem use `display: inline-block;` on `main`

```css
body {font-family: "Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS";
  width: 780px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555555}

#site {background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;}

.main {list-style-type: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
        display: inline-block; // <-- here
  width: 100%}

.main li {display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative}

.main li a {display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 12px 5px 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;}

.main a {text-decoration: none;
  color: black;}

.main2 li {position: absolute;
   display: none;
   width: 100%
   }
      
/*Changed this part*/
.main li:hover .main2 li  {display: block;}

.main2 li a {color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="site">
 <nav>
  <ul class="main">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Über mich</a></li>
   <li>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <!-- Move this inside li -->
    <ul class="main2">
     <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
    </ul>      
      </li>

   <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li>
        <a href="#">Links</a>
        <!-- Move this inside li -->
        <ul class="main2">
     <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Insta</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was my issue. Do you have a suggestion for how I can fix the gradient issue too? Because now that I removed the *overflow:hidden* thing, my linear gradient doesn't get displayed. I had *overflow:hidden* instead of 
*width: 100%*

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer. You juste have to add `display:inline-block`. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the .main2 menu displayed only when parent link is covered.
2 changes:
1) make a child ul tag part of the li (nest it)
2) change the display logic of :hover to act on child element (.main li:hover > ul)

Result:

```css
.main {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(  rgba(240,240,240,1),  rgba(240,240,240,0) );
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

.main li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.main li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 12px 5px 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.main2 {
  width: 100%;
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  padding:0;
}

.main2 li {
  width: 100%;
}

.main li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.main2 li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="site">
 <nav>
  <ul class="main">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Über mich</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
    <ul class="main2">
     <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
    </ul>
        </li>
   <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Links</a>
    <ul class="main2">
     <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Insta</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

If you are thinking about optimizing the styling, here is my version with less selectors:
https://codepen.io/VsevolodTS/pen/KRxeRL

Comment: This version also address gradient issue